# Why is my Flow Dynamic Record Choice not pulling in the right values?

Tags: visual-workflow

I created a dynamic record choice to pull in the values for a picklist on a specific record type. However, the values it pulls in isn't all correct, most of them are duplicated??

These are the values it is supposed to pull up:
[image]

However, theses are the values at runtime:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic record choice is designed to create a choice for each record, not for a field.  That is why there are dupes, it is pulling a list of records and displaying the value of the picklist field on the record.

As far as I know there is still no way to dynamically pull picklist choices for a specific record type - you must hard code them.

You can use a regular picklist choice resource, but it will give you all values for that picklist.